# pyspark df.withColumn with three conditions

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I have two columns that represents `'TeamName'` and `'MatchResult'` for example:

```
ManCity    L
Liverpool  D
Arsenal    W
```

I'm trying to create a third column that represents `'Points'` based on the match results of different football teams. So 3 points for Win, 1 for Draw, 0 for Lose

I've tried functions `.withColumn` using when and if, but can't get `syntax` right.

Thanks a lot in advance for your time

```
ManCity    L    0
Liverpool  D    1
Arsenal    W    3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col

df = df.withColumn("points", when(col("MatchResult") == "W", 3).when(col("MatchResult") == "D", 1).otherwise(0))
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your answer, I imported functions (from pyspark.sql.functions import col, expr, when). I might be missing somthing else I tried that sintaxis and this is what is coming up.

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'withColumn'

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-1835930437557426> in <module>
----> 1 dfHTPoints = dfHT.withColumn("HTP", when(col("HTR") == "H", 3).when(col("HTR") == "D", 1).otherwise(0))

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'withColumn'

Comment: What is `dfHT`? It is `NoneType`, please check if it's the same dataframe that you mentioned in the original question

Comment: dfHT is a new data frame that I've created using function select to filter data, as initial data was all in the same row and three columns  (H stands for when Home team win, D for when there's a Draw and A for when Away team wins)i.e.                                                              / ManCity    /  Liverpool   /  H  /  --
/ Liverpool  /    Arsenal     /   D /  --
/ Arsenal    / ManCity    /   A /  --

Comment: @ruben.lfdz please print that variable and paste the output in your question

Comment: I don't know how but I managed to sort it out by adding display(dfHT) when I created it. Thanks for your time